# sed command working in command line but not in script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, script, sed

I have a script with the follow code:

```
find . -name "*.html" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' n; do
sed -i -r 's/<font color="#bbbbbb">\.<\/font>.*?<input[^µ]*?mabulle\.hide\(\)">//1' "$n" 
sed -i -r 's/<\/body>/<a href="\.\/00Tree\.html">Back<\/a><\/body>/' "$n" #add back link
done
```

The second `sed` is not working. If I run

```
sed -i -r 's/<\/body>/<a href="\.\/00Tree\.html">Back<\/a><\/body>/' filename.html
```

from the command line it works perfectly.

The html files are named 0_name.html, 1_name.html, etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your second `sed` works after processing the first one from command line? Can you give a tiny html sample to understand better the meaning of _working_?

Comment: Oh boy. I just discovered why it was working. I was editing a copy of the script, not the one I was running. I'm feeling stupid.

Comment: @ToDo glad you found it, please close the answer out.

Answer (score 2):

There was nothing wrong with the code. I was simply editing a copy of the script instead of the one I was running.